# retrieve user comments with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I tried with:

me/feed

It returns the things posted in my profile

me?fields=posts

It returns the things I posted pretty much everywhere, but it doesn't return the responses (comments) I wrote in other people's posts.

me?fields=posts{comments}

It return the comments of the posts returned by the query above.

But I can't find the way to get MY comments on posts posted by OTHER people.

Is that possible?

Comment: U get some solution to get comments? i search same response..